# MySQL transaction: queries committed anyway

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I discovered PDO and transactions few days ago and they're great. Today I wrote my first transaction but it didn't end as expected. To test it I put a wrong **inexistent table** in one of the two queries and, independently of which one, the other (correct) one is committed anyway.

I read the syntax structure on some websites and it seems to be correct, but maybe the error is right there. The tables are InnoDB. Or better, phpMyAdmin, into the db overview's table, reports `MyISAM` on the last summary row but the column "*type*" of each table's row reports `InnoDB`; I think this could be 'cause MyISAM is the default type on the server, is that right?

Here's the code:

```
$conn = new PDO($db->getDsn(), $db->getUsername(), $db->getPassword());

try {
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO trips (country_code, year, img, showX) VALUES (:country_code, :year, :img, :showX)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':country_code' => strtolower($country_code), ':year' => $year, ':img' => $rename_response, ':showX' => $show_hide));
    $tripID = $conn->lastInsertId();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO trips_multilang (tripID, lang, country_name) VALUES (:tripID, :lang, :country_name)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':tripID' => $tripID, ':lang' => $trip_lang, ':country_name' => strtolower($country_name)));

    $conn->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: MyISAM is not transactional. Your tables need to be InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your $db class another method, `$db->getOptions()`, that returns an array

```
return [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
```

and then call PDO as

```
$conn = new PDO($db->getDsn(), $db->getUsername(), $db->getPassword(), $db->getoptions());
```

After that your code will start to catch up.
For now you are catching exceptions for nought, as none actually thrown.

On a side note, you must catch Exception, not PDOException and also [you must re-throw an exception in case of error](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions) instead of dying out.

Comment: A perfect and clean answer, thanks Your Common Sense! I tried both PDOException and Exception and both work so, just for the sake of curiosity, why should I catch the second one instead of the first one?